# Powershell 5.1 cannot use [System.Web.HttpUtility] inside class method

Tags: powershell, class

When using powershell `5.1.19041.1682`, I cannot use `[System.Web.HttpUtility]` inside a class method:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# This works fine
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("foo")

class Test {
  [void] Doit() {
    # This creates the error below
    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("bar")
  }
}

$d = [Test]::new()
$d.Doit()
```

Here is the output:

```
At C:\doit.ps1:7 char:6
+     [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("bar")
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpUtility].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

On the latest powershell (7.3) this problem does not happen.

If I comment the call inside `Doit()` it correctly prints "foo".

Can someone explain what is going on with 5.1? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Follow says it is only supported in Net 7 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-7.0#system-web-httputility-urlencode(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)

Comment: @jdweng: why does it work fine outside the class then?

Comment: One case it is using 7.3 and other case 5.1.  You may have older version of a cmdlet that is using older PS.

Comment: What? No I always test on 5.1, I just confirmed the problem didn't happen in 7.3 but that was in a docker container, the OS only has 5.1 installed.

Comment: Use find command inside and outside and see if you get same version : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/find-command?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: in powershell 7.3 this doesnt happen because the assembly is already loaded. see linked answer for possible solutions to this issue